# get_current_user_id() returns 0 even when I am logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

`get_current_user_id()` is returning `0` even when I am logged in. I am using it to add some values in the database but it always returns `0`.

```
<?php
include "class.Database.inc";
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
define ("DIR_PATH", dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads");
define ("BOOK_FOLDER" ,"/book");
define ("COVER_FOLDER","/cover");


function checkIfFileExistsAndReturnPath($location,$name,$ext){
    ...
}

function saveFile($file,$folder,$name)
{   
    ...

}

function uploadMedia($file, $post)
{
    ...
}

function returnJson ($message , $code)
{
        $msg = $message;
        $Code = $code;
        $array = array ('code' => $Code, 'message' => $msg); 
        header('Content-type: application/json'); 
        echo json_encode($array);
}

function authorExists ($id)
{
    if ($id == 0)
    {
        returnJson( "You are not logged in." , 6);
    }
    else {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $connection = $db->getConnection();

    $sql_query = "Select * from gp_posts where post_type = 'authorbook' AND post_author = '".$id."'";

    $result = $connection->query($sql_query);
    $number = 0;

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $number++;
    }

    if ($number > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
}

function getAuthorId ($id)
{
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $connection = $db->getConnection();

    $sql_query = "Select ID from gp_posts where post_type = 'authorbook' AND post_author = '".$id."'";

    $result = $connection->query($sql_query);
    $author_post_id = NULL;
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $author_post_id = $row['ID'];
    }

    if ($author_post_id != NULL)
    {
        return $author_post_id;
    }

    return NULL;
}

function createAuthor ($id)
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $current_user->user_firstname." ".$current_user->user_lastname ,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => $user_id,
            'post_type' => 'authorbook',
            'comment_status' => 'closed'
            );


            // Insert the post into the database
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post , $wp_error );

            if ($post_id)
            {
                 return $post_id;
            }
}


$code = 0;
function cleanPostData($post_data){
    $post_data = trim($post_data);
    $post_data = stripslashes($post_data);
    $post_data = htmlspecialchars($post_data);
    return $post_data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $title = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']));

    $genre = cleanPostData($_POST['genre']);

    $language = cleanPostData($_POST['language']);

    $book_file = $_FILES['book'];
    $book = $_FILES['book']['tmp_name'];
    $book_file_name = $_FILES['book']['name'];

    $book_description = cleanPostData($_POST['book_description']); 

    $book_front_cover_file = $_FILES['book_front_cover'];
    $book_front_cover_name = $_FILES['book_front_cover']['name'];
    $book_front_cover = $_FILES['book_front_cover']['tmp_name'];
    $book_front_cover_id = "";

    $book_back_cover_file = $_FILES['book_back_cover'];
    $book_back_cover_name = $_FILES['book_back_cover']['name'];
    $book_back_cover = $_FILES['book_back_cover']['tmp_name'];
    $book_back_cover_id = "";

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    //$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
    $author = authorExists($user_id) ? getAuthorId($user_id) : createAuthor($user_id);



    //echo var_export($book_file_name);echo "<br>";

    if (empty($title))
    {
        returnJson("Please provide the title of your book." , 1);
    }

    else if (empty($genre))
    {   
        returnJson("Please select a genre.", 2);
    }

    else if (empty($book_file_name))
    {   
        returnJson("Please select a book." , 3);
    }

    else if (empty($book_description))
    {   
        returnJson("Please provide a sdescription about the book." , 4);
    }


    /*else if (empty($author))
    {
        returnJson("Please select an author, if your desired author is not in the list you can create a new author from above." , 5);

    }*/

    else {
        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: No code no help!

Comment: I'm sorry, there isn't enough information to go on.  All I can tell is that you are running a query somewhere...

Comment: Please provide some of your code efforts so at least someone can suggest further

Comment: show some part of your code, how are you using this function

Comment: Please check now, I have uploaded the code.

Answer (score 5):

In case you're attempting a REST api request, it is by default non-authenticated and the user ID automatically set to 0, see the REST api [codex on authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/):

> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to wp_rest. These can then be passed to the API via the _wpnonce data parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via the X-WP-Nonce header. If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re logged into WordPress.

you can remedy this by simply adding a nonce to your request,

either in your AJAX header,

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/uid',
  method: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', settings.nonce);
  }
})
```

or using a hidden field in your form,

```
$_wpnonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = '_wpnonce' value = '$_wpnonce' />";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `get_current_user_id()` function inside the `init` action to get current user id.

Like this:

```
add_action('init', 'myFunction');

function myFunction(){
   $user_ID= get_current_user_id();     
   // THEN DO YOUR CODE OR QUERY TO ADD VALUE IN DB.
}
```

Hope this will helpfull and works for you. Thank You.

Comment: This is the right answer.